# Simple JQuery AutoComplete w/ Javascript Callback to format reponse

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, callback, formatted

I am new to JSON and trying to figure out how to get this real simple autocomplete working with some formatted response.  (all jquery autocompletes I see use the huge ui library's that I would rather stay far away from).

This is what I have so far:

```
$(function() {
     // u check
     $('#search-input').keyup(function() { 
     $.ajax({ 
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            type: "POST", 
            url: "/includes/myautocomplete/tags.php", 
            data: "callback=autocomplete&q="+$('#search-input').val(), 
            jsonp: 'autocomplete',
            success: function(json){
                $('#search-resp').html(json);
            }
        });
    });
```

});

I am trying to format the response with:

```
function autocomplete(json) {
  var html ='<ul>';
  for(i=0;i<json.length;i++) {
    var n = json[i];
    html = '<li>'+n['tagname']+'</li>';
  }
  html = '</ul>';
  return html;
}
```

My PHP looks like:

```
# JSON-encode the response
$json_response = json_encode($array);

# Optionally: Wrap the response in a callback function for JSONP cross-domain support
if($_POST["callback"]) {
   $json_response = $_POST["callback"] . "(" . $json_response . ")";
}

# Return the response
echo $json_response;
```

What am I doing wrong?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: also help to see sample of data sent from php unless you are certain your `autocomplet(json)` formatter is working properly

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to parse the json first:

```
success: function(data){
  var json = $.parseJSON(data);
  //then display it...
}
```

Comment: k.  thanks.  I added that, but then what?  How does this ajax code grab the autocomplete function to format the response?  Sorry such a noob to all this.

Comment: `$.ajax` will do the parsing automatically for json or xml when `dataType` is set accordingly

Comment: do what charlieftl has said, that should get you the desired results. In my case, whenever I use ajax, regardless of the set dataType, I still have to parse it before using it.

Comment: @domo270897  try `console.log( $.type(data))` next time... doubtful it returns `string` when response is json(p) and dataType is set

Comment: @charlietfl just did that and it does seem to return `string`, probably some issue on my end, thanks for the advice though!

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for the fiddle, I understand that I should be seeing object rather than string as a response, but I cant seem to find an issue in my code.

Comment: still not having any luck.
    `success: function(data){
     var json = $.parseJSON(data);
     var html = autocomplete(json);
     $('#search-resp1').html(html);
    }`

Comment: have you tried with just the solution posted by @charlietfl ? cause that might work. Also, I was going to suggest that you style it on the PHP side of things, like this: `$json_response = {response: '<ul> foreach($array as $word) {echo "<li>$word</li>"}</ul>'}` - something like that.

Comment: get rid of the callback... you are getting ahead of yourself trying to use `jsonp` on local domain when can't get it working as regular json first. Also data has no `tagname` property as in your formatter

Answer (score 0):

For starters you never call your format function

You have:

```
success: function(json){
      $('#search-resp').html(json);
}
```

which is trying to insert the full response object into the element as html.

Assuming your `autocomplete` function properly parses the returned array or object your code should look more like:

```
success: function(json){
      var jsonFormattedToHtml=autocomplete(json)
      $('#search-resp').html(jsonFormattedToHtml);
}
```

**EDIT**

Your html fomatting code has several flaws.

The biggest one is you need to concatenate `html` by using `html +=` instead of `html=` after you first define it. Using `=` only wipes out any value previously set, so output of your function will simply be the closing `</ul>` only.

Also object properties in formatter don't match data shown.

Here's a working demo

http://jsfiddle.net/vgbK8/2/

Comment: thank you. still not getting a formatted out put. Just the json array

Comment: start simple and don't send the `callback`, use `json` only ,will need to set crossDomain option if trying to force jsonp on same domain, and provide sample of response  data. There is no way you should see array in html output if you pass it through your formatter function first

Comment: response data looks like:  
`autocomplete([{"name":"Test","tagslug":"test"}])`

Comment: see my answer edit about other problems in code and a working demo

Comment: still nothing works. If i view the console my out put is a json array with the callback prefix....but thats it.

Comment: GET RID OF `callback` in the url, or disable it in php..and set `dataType:'json` You aren't following concepts of `jsonp` on local domain yet

Comment: Thank you for the JS Fiddle.   Could you include a text field with keyup for autocomplete?

Comment: you can easily modify a fiddle yourself and save new version using either `fork` or `update`. Try it and if have proble post link after save

Comment: thanx again.  i dont really know what i am doing here... but....http://jsfiddle.net/vgbK8/4/

Comment: updated to work  http://jsfiddle.net/vgbK8/7/ Of course this demo will always send same results since don't have server to create resonse. You will need to change to `data:{q:$('#search-input').val()}`. Also fiddle only allows `POST`

Comment: THANK YOU.  This helped and I was able to get it to work.  Thank you for your time on this.

Answer (score 0):

Simple autocomplete textbox

Just include JS library in `<head>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://services.iperfect.net/js/IP_generalLib.js"></script>
```

In `<body>` tag:

```
<input type="text" name="testne" id="testneer" onkeypress="IP_autoComplete('http://services.iperfect.net/ajax/countries.php?name=',this.id,'testDiv',event,'')">
<div id='testDiv'></div>
```